# const pointer pointing to a const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I'm working with some memory pointers. I don't want to use hash defines, please leave that discussion aside. I would just like to know why this does not compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const unsigned long *const pMemAddrA = (unsigned long *) 0x00000200ul;
static const unsigned long *const pMemAddrB = pMemAddrA;

int main (void)
{
    printf("%x", (unsigned int) pMemAddrB);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler output gcc:

```
||=== TestConst, Debug ===|
 ...main.c|4|error: initializer element is not constant|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

EDIT:

After reading the answers, I'm happy to know how to go about this problem.

However I do not understand why it is a problem. From what I know static memory gets allocated at program start. I know there is issue if variables "live" in different files and the order in which the variables are allocated cannot be guaranteed by the compiler. However, if both variables "live" in the same file - just as both variables living in the same function - I would think the compiler can assure that memory gets allocated in the order of variables being declared in the file, and therefore I don't understand why declaring and initializing a const pointer to another const pointer is an issue. I'd be happy if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: What does not work mean?  If it's not compiling post the compiler error, if it's showing unexpected output post the output.

Comment: If you would add *what* "does not work" means, we could help you much better.

Comment: Unfortunately, declaring a variable const doesn't mean that it is a constant, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointers have file scope, so the initialisers must be constant expressions. `pMemAddrA` isn't a constant expression, therefore can't be used to initialise a variable with static storage.

It can be used to initialise a variable in block scope, so if you move your declarations inside `main` (and make at least the second non-static), it will compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

    const unsigned long *const pMemAddrA = (unsigned long *) 0x00000200ul;
    const unsigned long *const pMemAddrB = pMemAddrA;

    printf("%x", (unsigned int) pMemAddrB);
    return 0;
}
```

If the two pointers must be declared at file scope, there is no way to prevent either repeating the initialising expression,

```
static const unsigned long *const pMemAddrA = (unsigned long *) 0x00000200ul;
static const unsigned long *const pMemAddrB = (unsigned long *) 0x00000200ul;
```

or `#define`ing it.

Comment: I get the same result without using static.

Comment: The declarations are at file scope, so the variables have static storage, whether you declare them explicitly `static` or not.

Comment: Okay, that I understand better.

Comment: Hm. Sorry I want to understand this thoroughly... if a const has file scope (static, whether explicitly declared or not) it is not "really" const, while within a code block it is? I believe it, but why?

Comment: The `const` has nothing to do with it. Stuff declared outside any function has file scope (and static storage duration). Such variables can only be initialised with "constant expressions". A `const` variable is **not** a constant expression. A constant expression is an integer literal, or a simple arithmetic expression using literals (`3 + 5 * sizeof(int)`). A `const` variable is just a variable you cannot modify (rather, that you cannot use to modify the object stored there).

Comment: Okay I understand. But it leads to another question, which is: Why can I only use const expressions to initialize file scope/static variables?

Comment: @AudioDroid: Terminologically, in C language a `const` object is *never* a constant. C and C++ differ greatly in that regard. In C language the only *constants* are *literal values* and *enum members*. There are no other constants in C. So, when the language requires a *constant*, it means it requires a literal values or a enum member. `const` objects in C can be called "constant variables" or in some other way, but they are not called constants. The latter term is reserved for a different meaning in C.

Comment: Short answer: because the standard says so. Longer answer: I don't know the reasons, but since objects with static storage are initialised at program startup, allowing only constant expressions leaves the order of initialisation up to the implementation, and the committee likes to leave such details to the implementation. If non-constant expressions were allowed, the order of initialisation would need to take care of the dependencies, that would tie the implementations' hands too much.

Comment: Hey guys. Many thanks to the in-depth answers. I very much appreciate it. I haven't learned that much about C in a LONG time! Great stuff!

Comment: @AudioDroid: The reason you are required to use constant expressions is to avoid generating any *code* for static initialization (which would have to run before `main`). With constant expression requirement, all static objects can be initialized at compile-time and begin their lives in pre-initailized state. That's the basic rationale behind this C requirement. In general, C language attempts to minimize the amount of implicit code, i.e. all code should be explicitly written by the user.

Answer (score 2):

You don't describe what "does not work", but I guess you mean that the line

```
static const unsigned long *const pMemAddrB = pMemAddrA;
```

produces the error

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

.

The solution is that indeed this initializer is not considered as constant. Instead, a memory area for `pMemAddrA` is set aside and the value `0x00000200ul` is written in there. From there on, it is a value which sits somewhere in memory, and not a constant expression.

Depending on what you want to do with that, you could add another pointer indirection such as

```
static const unsigned long *const * const pMemAddrB = &pMemAddrA;
```

and access it with `*pMemAddrB` instead of `pMemAddrB`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand to some extend. Does this mean unless using hash-defines for this, I can't make it work??? Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: @AudioDroid You can repeat the same constant expression you used to initialise `pMemAddrA`, or you can declare the variable in block scope, and use `pMemAddrA` as initialiser for `pMemAddrB`.

Comment: @AudioDroid I have added a workaround which may or may not be useful for what you plan to do.